# "Refinement" of the existence of faithful representations of C*-algebras?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Conway, in [a course in operator theory](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=gtnMW_uH7DcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=a%20course%20in%20operator%20theory&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=9hvLU7vmMMzJsQTrkYKYDQ&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=a%20course%20in%20operator%20theory&f=false), brings the statement 1. below as a theorem and statement 2. below as an exercise. Still, he states that 2. refines 1., but I can't see it.

1. Every C*-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ has a faithful representation. $A$ has a faithful representation $(\pi,\mathcal{H})$ with $\mathcal{H}$ separable if and only if there are a countable number of states on $\mathcal{A}$ that separate the points of $\mathcal{A}_+$, each of which defines a separable representation. In particular, every separable C*-algebra has a faithful, separable representation.
2. If $\mathcal{A}$ is a separable C*-algebra and $\left\{\phi_n\right\}$ a weak* dense sequence in the state space, put $\phi=\sum_n2^{-n}\phi_n$. Then $\phi$ is a state and the representation $\pi_{\phi}$ is faithful.

How does 2. refine 1.?

Comment: 2. refines 1. because the representation constructed in 1. is, in general, a direct sum of infinitely many GNS representations, i.e., representations constructed from states on $\mathcal{A}$, whilst 2. gives you a *single* GNS representation that does the job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Branimir had posted an answer as a comment:

> `2.` refines `1.` because the representation constructed in `1.` is, in general, a direct sum of infinitely many GNS representations, i.e., representations constructed from states on $\mathcal A$, whilst `2.` gives you a *single* GNS representation that does the job.